# Tx to a multisig address in testnet not working

Tags: testnet, multi-signature, blockexplorer

I've sent a tx to a newly created multisig address on testnet, but I don't understand why I didn't get the funds yet.

What I've done so far was to create 3 separate wallets, and get the 3 pubkeys to create the multisig address from python bitcoinrpc, and just in case I've used the command line too:

```
>>> multi_list = ['0355f3c263aeb7859e53d3549d3c9bc99cd581154d16e259fe390e029d6bda5b78',
...     '030a53f844570b8c26794276e205cdeab87ab0d7802d2abb5116a5472e3adc7dc1',
...     '0210b58f846754a9d0d70e226688e0693a241fd58e315d738399e40e68308b88f9']
>>> btc.createmultisig(2, multi_list) 
{u'redeemScript': u'52210355f3c263aeb7859e53d3549d3c9bc99cd581154d16e259fe390e029d6bda5b7821030a53f844570b8c26794276e205cdeab87ab0d7802d2abb5116a5472e3adc7dc1210210b58f846754a9d0d70e226688e0693a241fd58e315d738399e40e68308b88f953ae', u'address': u'2N8DirDvhxVEm61b3JMc75Hsdqe8aWg9Vvu'}
```

Then, I've sent from another account some coins

```
>>> btc.sendfrom('myaccount', '2N8DirDvhxVEm61b3JMc75Hsdqe8aWg9Vvu', 0.15)
u'fa9982d579877ba31ed9c530ae99df1f67c1632ae8f3c7e4db8af1fbc442dfe8'
```

But on [blockexplorer](http://blockexplorer.com/testnet/tx/fa9982d579877ba31ed9c530ae99df1f67c1632ae8f3c7e4db8af1fbc442dfe8) the vout address is marked as "unknown", and on [btclook](http://testnet.btclook.com/txn/fa9982d579877ba31ed9c530ae99df1f67c1632ae8f3c7e4db8af1fbc442dfe8) also the output was marked as "???"

The raw tx says, in the ScriptPub of the vout marks the "type': 'scripthash'"

What have I done wrong?
Are multisig addresses working on testnet? (I assume yes)

Additionaly, I'm using bitcoin core v0.9.1 which was recently released.

Comment: You could post your update as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: looks like the testnet blockexporer don't know how to handle the multisig addresses (probably because it was hardcoded the p2sh magicbyte from mainnet) and shows them as "strange", but my TX was confirmed ok and i was able to spend the incoming txs.